# WebRTC/Mediarecorder stream to FFMPEG JS

Tags: webrtc, mediarecorder

I'm trying to set up a process in Javascript process where I take either a MediaRecorder stream or a WebRTC RTCPeerConnection and use that live 'stream' from the webcam/device and feed it into a Javascript compiled [FFMPEG object](https://github.com/bgrins/videoconverter.js).

I'm doing this all in the context of the browser (with it's limitations).  I've tried several things, like creating a blob and passing that into FFMPEG, or creating an SDP file from the RTCPeerconnection process, but all without much luck.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end?